# Smooth Moving Ball with Arrow keys javascript

Tags: javascript

How do you make the ball move smoothly every time I click an arrow key. Everytime I click an arrow key, it get chunky and only moves every 1 second if I hold it. I want it so if I press it for a long time, it moves fairly fast and smooth.

```js
 var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var ball = {
  pos: {x: 500,y: 300},
  speed: 5,
 };
 var FPS = 30;
window.onload = function() {
 setInterval(function() {
  gameBack();
 }, 1000/FPS);
}
// background code
function gameBack() {
 drawRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height, 'Black');
 colorCircle(ball.pos.x,ball.pos.y,10, 'white');
}
// Rectangle Code
function drawRect(leftX,topY,width,height, drawColor) {
 ctx.fillStyle = drawColor;
 ctx.fillRect(leftX,topY,width,height);
}
//Circle Code
function colorCircle(centerX,centerY,radius, drawColor) {
 ctx.fillStyle = drawColor;
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(centerX,centerY,radius,0,Math.PI*2,true);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.fill();
}
//Game Controls
document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    if (event.keyCode === 37) { //Left
     xBall(-5);
    } else if (event.keyCode === 39) { //Right
     xBall(5);
    } else if (event.keyCode === 38) { //Up
     yBall(-5);
    } else if (event.keyCode === 40) { //Down
     yBall(5);
    }
});
function yBall(offset) {
 ball.pos.y += offset;
}
function xBall(offset) {
 ball.pos.x += offset;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="game" width=800 height=600></canvas>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Body animation isn't smooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365542/body-animation-isnt-smooth)

Answer (score 0):

Add a direction vector.  Let the keys control the direction vector and use the direction vector to update the position in each frame.  Depending on how you update the direction vector, you can make the ball gain speed or slowly stop.

For example:

```js
 var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var ball = {
  pos: {x: 500,y: 300},
        direction: { x: 0, y: 0 },
  speed: 5,
        brake: 0.9, // smaller number stop faster, max 0.99999
 };
 var FPS = 30;
    window.onload = function() {
     setInterval(function() {
            animate();
      gameBack();
     }, 1000/FPS);
    };
    function animate() {
        ball.pos.x += ball.direction.x * ball.speed;
        ball.pos.y += ball.direction.y * ball.speed;
        ball.direction.x *= ball.brake;
        ball.direction.y *= ball.brake;
    }
    // background code
    function gameBack() {
     drawRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height, 'Black');
     colorCircle(ball.pos.x,ball.pos.y,10, 'white');
    }
    // Rectangle Code
    function drawRect(leftX,topY,width,height, drawColor) {
     ctx.fillStyle = drawColor;
     ctx.fillRect(leftX,topY,width,height);
    }
    //Circle Code
    function colorCircle(centerX,centerY,radius, drawColor) {
     ctx.fillStyle = drawColor;
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(centerX,centerY,radius,0,Math.PI*2,true);
     ctx.closePath();
     ctx.fill();
    }
    //Game Controls
    document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
        if (event.keyCode === 37) { //Left
         xBall(-1);
        } else if (event.keyCode === 39) { //Right
         xBall(1);
        } else if (event.keyCode === 38) { //Up
         yBall(-1);
        } else if (event.keyCode === 40) { //Down
         yBall(1);
        }
    });
    function yBall(offset) {
     ball.direction.y += offset;
    }
    function xBall(offset) {
     ball.direction.x += offset;
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="game" width=800 height=600></canvas>
```